# Disabled Button is still callable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

The code below creates a GUI with a Button. When I press the Button the Button gets grayed out and after the "Plus" function finishes the Button changes to normal/enabled.
The Problem is that I can still click on the disabled Button, so the "Plus" function starts immediately(is stackable) after the first one finishes.

Does anybody know why this happen?

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

fenster = Tk()
fenster.geometry("840x480+00+150")
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
A1S =16 #GPIO Pin 16


# Moves a Steppermotor
def Plus(): 
    for i in range(1000):
        GPIO.output(A1S, True)
        time.sleep(0.0018)
        GPIO.output(A1S, False)


def GUIsperren(): #Disable Button
    b1["state"] = "disabled"
def GUIentsperren(): #Enable Button
    b1["state"] = "normal"


def moveaxis():
    GUIsperren()
    Plus()
    GUIentsperren()

b1=Button(fenster, text="PLUS", command=moveaxis)
b1.place(x=190, y=180,height=80, width=80)

fenster.mainloop()
```

I also tried this but get the same result:

```
def Plus():
    b1["state"] = "disabled"
    for i in range(200):
        GPIO.output(A1S, True)
        time.sleep(0.0018)
        GPIO.output(A1S, False)
    b1["state"] = "normal"
```

Comment: Your whole process takes only 0.36 second. Looks to me the disable/enable is done in an instant.

Comment: You're right. I accidentally copied the function of my program with the smallest amount of steps. I noticed it in a for loop with 1000 steps.